# Unable to install monkey talk ios agent in my xcode app

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, agent

I am trying to test an iphone application using automation tool,Monkey Talk(inherited from Fone monkey),which is a product of Gorilla Logic.I have strictly followed the Gorilla Logic official website in setting up the process.It was said that,before testing the application using Monkey Talk,we need to install Monkey Talk ios agent in xcode.Here is the link for setting up the same.

https://www.gorillalogic.com/book/ios

Despite of following all the steps,I am unable to install ios agent in xcode.

I get the below warning while running the app

[image]

Can any one please help me out on this.

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says the directory /Users/zyksa001/Desktop/Eshwar/Desktop/EventsReminder doesn't exist.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the multiple Desktops.

Comment: But the fact is the directory exists in system,as I have checked with it manually and using command prompt,wonder why it is unable to recognize :O

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Oh I see. The arguments aren't using bash quoting rules, so that's actually looking for a path that has the quotes embedded in it. Interestingly, your command-line arguments also include the same path without the quotes, so you can just delete that build argument entirely.

Comment: Can you please clarify me regarding multiple desktops,did you mean since desktop is existing by default,it is clashing with folder name "Desktop" !

Comment: Deleting the build argument,what do you mean exactly? totally confused!

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: The only way for you to have a garbage build argument like that is if you added it to your build settings. It must be in there somewhere. Find it and delete it.

Comment: I found out why the warning is occurring,in build settings,Library search paths,I have added the path with double quotes along with the path without quotes,I have removed the path with quotes and now I could see no warnings what so ever,but the problem is still I am unable to install monkey talk ios agent in my xcode app :(

Comment: Can you please once check with EDIT part of the post,your kind patience is important for a beginner like me :)

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: libMonkeyTalk defines a category on `UIStepper`, which was a class introduced in iOS 5.0. You're targeting the 4.3 SDK. This is causing a linker error. It seems libMonkeyTalk requires iOS 5.0 or higher.

Comment: Oh,will check with the same and get back to you,thanks for the response

Comment: Actually it was mentioned in Monkey Talk FAQ section that "The MonkeyTalk Agent for iOS requires iOS 4.0 or greater",you can follow this link: http://www.qualitytesting.info/profiles/blogs/monkey-talk-install-guide for reference

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Perhaps that's out of date? The linker error clearly indicates it requires `UIStepper`.

Comment: Hmm,so it means I need to upgrade my ios version to 5.0??

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Yes, if you want to use this library, you need to bump your SDK to 5.0, and likely your minimum version as well.

Comment: Yeah Kevin Ballard,some how managed to upgrade my xcode version from 4.0 to 4.2(ios 5 included),but when I try to run the application selecting iphone 5.0 simulator,I am facing crash issue in main.m(autorelease),despite of fixing all the leak issues after analyzing the application!!

Comment: @EshwarChaitanya: Sounds like a completely different issue than the one described in this SO post.